# sync txt files from multiple directories using rsync

Tags: backup, wildcard, rsync

The job is to download "txt" files from multiple directories in the server. For example, we'd like to download all the "txt" files from the following directories.

```
/home/user/dir1
/home/user/dir2
/home/user/dirHello
```

My solution is to create three separate commands and each command looks like:

```
rsync -ar --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" username@hostname:/home/user/dir1(dir2,dirHello) destination_dir
```

It works! But I'm wondering can I do the job in one command?

Some reference links:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174674/rsync-a-list-of-directories-with-absolute-path-in-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it supply one or more source dirs to rsync so you could just do this:

```
rsync -ar --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" username@hostname:/home/user/dir1 username@hostname:/home/user/dir2 username@hostname:/home/other_user/dirHello destination_dir
```

Comment: what if dir1, dir2, dirHello do not share a common parent directory /home/uer?

Comment: thanks so much. Another quick question, what if I do not want to include the results from sub-directories

Comment: I think you can change --include="*/" to --include="/*"

Comment: I made it work by replacing --include="star/" with --include="/star". I kind of do not understand why it works. In my thought, I think using --include="/" should be enough for my purpose.